# Why one value doesn't pass through Angular Frontend even though other values pass well?

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot

The data I added to the addForm, doesn't pass to the database(MySQL) through the frontend.
Example: I entered different values via Add form. After submitting that Console shows,

```
assignedJob: "1"
assignedVehicle: "IN6562"
startSiteVisit: false
state:"Pending"
tmember1: null
```

Here I entered tMember1 as "Amal" But that value pass as null.
I checked many times. No syntax error. The whole code is same as other codes.

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Assign Team Member</label>  
    <br>
    <label for="tMember1">Member 1 Name:</label>
    <input type="text" ngModel 
           name="tMember1" 
           class="form-control" 
           id="tMember1" 
           placeholder="Assign a Member" required> 
</div>
```

**service.ts code:**

```
export interface SiteVisit{
    siteVisitName: string;
    siteVisitId: number;
    tMember1: String;
    assignedVehicle: string;
    state:string;
    assignedJob: string
}
```

**component.ts code:**

```
const siteVisit: SiteVisit = {
            
            tMember1: addForm.value.tMember1,
            assignedVehicle: assignedVehicle,
            startSiteVisit: false,
            state: state,
            assignedJob: addForm.value.assignedJob,
           
          };
```

How can I fix it?

P.S.:
Here I solved above problem using memberOne instead of tMember1. But I don't know exact reason of above error. Can Some one explain what is the error. Can't we use numbers in variables?

Comment: The input for tMember1 is commented out and doesn't use 2 way data binding (banana in a box). Please update your question to a minimal example and clarify the issue.

Comment: @AndrewAllen I added data as assignedJob: "1" assignedVehicle: "IN6562" startSiteVisit: false state:"Pending" tmember1: "Amal" . But data pass as assignedJob: "1" assignedVehicle: "IN6562" startSiteVisit: false state:"Pending" tmember1: null

Comment: in which point do you send your data to your database?

Comment: See that Angular is case sensitive, it's not the same `tmember1` than `tMember1`